# minimization problem

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I've encountered an optimization problem which would appreciate some help with :

the problem is stated as follows :

$$\min_{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_N}. \sqrt{\sum^N_{i=1} \alpha_i^2 \sigma_i} + \sum^N_{i=1}\alpha_i\beta_i + \mu $$

s.t $$\sum^N_{i=1}\alpha_{i} = 1,
\hspace{1cm}\alpha_i > 0\hspace{0.5cm}\forall i 
$$ ,

$$\sigma_i,\beta_i,\mu >0 \hspace{0.5cm}  \, \forall i = 1,...,N$$
are positive constants

I tried using lagrange multipliers but reached some form in which i couldn't continue further.

Can anyone suggest another approach that I can follow ?

Comment: Is there a reason that in the minimum solution $\mu$ will be big? I would try to minimize $\mu$ as possible, but it must stay positive.. hence no minimum exists. If you find a minimum, take $\mu / 2$ and you got a better solution

Comment: $\mu,\beta_i,\sigma_i$ are positive constants

Comment: Is $\alpha_i<0$ allowed?

Comment: sorry missed adding that, no $alpha_i$ are stricly positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the positiveness of $\alpha$ The Lagrangian reads

$$
L(\alpha,\lambda,\mu) = f(\alpha) - \lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i-1\right)
$$

where $f(\alpha) = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i\alpha_i^2}+ \sum_{i=1}^N\beta_i\alpha_i$. The stationary points for $L$ are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = \cases{\frac{\sigma_k\alpha_k}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i\alpha_i^2}}+\beta_k-\lambda=0,\ \ k = 1,\cdots,N\\
\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i=1
}
$$

or

$$
\nabla L = \cases{\alpha_k=\frac{1}{\sigma_k}\left(\lambda_0-\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N\sigma_i\alpha_i^2}\beta_k\right),\ \ k = 1,\cdots,N\\
\sum_{i=1}^N\alpha_i=1
}
$$

to eliminate $\lambda_0$ we add for all $k$ the first $N$ equations giving

$$
1 = \lambda_0\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i}-\sqrt{\sum_{j=1}^N\sigma_j\alpha_j^2}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\beta_i}{\sigma_i}
$$

and after $\lambda_0$ substitution we get

$$
\alpha_k = \frac{1}{\sigma_k}\left(\frac{1}{S_{\sigma}}\left(1+\sqrt{S_{\alpha}}S_{\beta/\sigma}\right)+\sqrt{S_{\alpha}}\beta_k\right)
$$

Here

$$
\cases{
S_{\alpha} = \sum_{j=1}^N\sigma_j\alpha_j^2\\
S_{\beta/\sigma} = \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\beta_i}{\sigma_i}\\
S_{\sigma} = \sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{\sigma_i}
}
$$

This give us an iterative formula to calculate successive $\alpha_k$. Follows a MATHEMATICA script implementing the procedure. This script corrects the negative $\alpha_k$ to $0$. This procedure usually converges and the results can be compared with the corresponding minimization command `NMinimize`

```
n = 17;
SeedRandom[1]
s = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
b = RandomReal[{0, 1}, n];
A = Table[a[k], {k, 1, n}];
obj = Sqrt[Sum[s[[k]] a[k]^2, {k, 1, n}]] + Sum[b[[k]] a[k], {k, 1, n}];

A0 = Thread[A -> 1/n];
Sbs = Sum[b[[k]]/s[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
Ss = Sum[1/s[[k]], {k, 1, n}];
A1 = A /. A0;
error = 10^-9;

For[j = 1, j <= 500, j++,
 SQS1 = Sqrt[Sum[s[[k]] a[k]^2, {k, 1, n}]] /. A0;
 A0 = Thread[A -> Table[1/s[[k]] ((1 + SQS1 Sbs)/Ss - SQS1 b[[k]]), {k, 1, n}]];
 A2 = A /. A0;
 A2 = Table[If[A2[[k]] > 0, A2[[k]], 0], {k, 1, Length[A2]}];
 sA = Total[A2];
 d = 1/sA;
 A2 = d A2;
 del = Max[Abs[A2 - A1]];
 If[del < error, Print[{j, (obj /. Thread[A -> A2]), A2}]; Break[]]; 
 A1 = A2
]

pos = Table[a[k] > 0, {k, 1, n}];
restrs = Join[pos, {Sum[a[k], {k, 1, n}] - 1 == 0}];
sol = Chop[Quiet@NMinimize[{obj, restrs}, A]];
{sol[[1]], A /. sol[[2]]}
```

Comment: Impressive, Thank you for the help!